# Can the enlightened badge be earned where a user answers their own question?

Tags: discussion, badges

The Enlightened badge has the following description

> First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes

My [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3791/is-dr-crane-scarecrow-part-of-the-league-of-shadows/3793#3793) has 11 up votes and seeing as it is the only answer it was clearly the first answer.

So shouldn't I be awarded the Enlightened badge?

Answering my own question shouldn't matter as it still has to be up voted to 10 so it has to be a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't get the badge for self-answers.

Reference:

- [Clarification Enlightened badge for own answered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113109/clarification-enlightened-badge-for-own-answered-question)